Determining $a$ from $x^{3}-20x+24a=\sqrt{4x^{2}-80x+48a}$
If $b$ denotes the sum of all values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a unique $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the relation
$$x^{3}-20x+24a=\sqrt{4x^{2}-80x+48a}$$
Find the value of $12b$.

Here's attempt at my solution, please correct me in any way if there's some fallacy happen to be in my solution process.
We square both sides to get \begin{equation} x^{6}+400x+576a^{2}+2(-20x^{4}+240ax^{3}-480ax)=4x^{2}-80x+48a\tag{1} \end{equation}
From $(1)$ I move all the ones with $a$'s to the RHS and leave the rest on the LHS.
$$x^{6}-40x^{4}+396x^{2}+80x=-48ax^{3}+960ax+48a-576a^{2}\tag{2}$$
(This is the part where I think I'm wrong) I then argued that to have a unique $x$ solution, the $a$'s must match the LHS. Notice how there is no $x^{3}$ term thus $a=0$. And the other case is, notice how there is an $x$ term in the LHS so $80=960a \implies a=\frac{1}{12}$.
I thought "Oh wow this is pretty convenient" since now $b=0+ \frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{12} \implies 12b=1$
I'm not so sure with my argument, can anyone point out my mistake?

Before discussing the validity of your assertion, you must provide a more explicit specification for $~"a~$ matching the LHS".  It looks like you are going exponent by exponent, determining any $~a~$ so that the $~x^k~$ terms match on each side, and then appending that particular value of $~a~$ to the set of satisfying values.  I don't see the logic here.  Further, you have suggested satisfying values of $~a~$ as $~{0, 1/12}.~$  Please show your work verifying that each of these two values is a satisfying value.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Re last comment : which contest is the problem from, if any?  Have you been given any tools that you think are pertinent?

Yeah that part where I equate the $a$'s is wrong, I didn't really know where to go from there :/

"I didn't really know where to go from there" : see the protocol article that I linked to.

In order to have real solutions, for the RHS, we need $25-3a\ge 0 \implies a\le \frac{25}3$ and studying the case $a=\frac{25}3$ we see there is a solution, and varying continuously a we have infinitely many solutions with an unique root. It seems the question is not well posed in that way.
